# Python - Get CSV content from url and parse to an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, url

I have a problem.

I want to get the content of a CSV file from an url and then parse it to an array. This is the code I have now:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url="https://www.test.com/csv.php"
dataset = requests.get(url, verify=False).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dataset.decode('utf-8')))

data = []
for row in df: # each row is a list
    data.append(row)
```

But when I execute this code, I only get the first row of the CSV and the values are between this -> '

```
['1', '4', '0']
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
1,4,0
0,1,1
1,1,0
0,1,1
1,1,0
0,3,1
1,1,0
0,3,1
1,1,0
```

And I am hoping to get an array like this:

```
[[1,4,0],
 [0,1,1],
 [1,1,0],
 [0,1,1],
 [1,1,0],
 [0,3,1],
 [1,1,0],
 [0,3,1],
 [1,1,0]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Using df.values gives me this:

```
[[0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 3. 0.]]
```

But that does not seem to be correct, because the first row has to be [1,4,0].
Also I need a -> , <- as seperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop: `.values` will return a matrix

```
url="https://www.test.com/csv.php"
dataset = requests.get(url, verify=False).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dataset.decode('utf-8')), header=None, sep=',')
data=df.values
```

Comment: @Vreesie Probably you need to disable header. Default delimiter is comma

Comment: Added your code and values seem to be right, but still seperated with a dot and not with a comma!?

Comment: @Vreesie print dataset and df, please

Answer (score 1):

According to pandas documentation, to iterate rows you should use:

```
df.iterrows()
```

as indicated in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for

Comment: I need it to be an array with [[]]

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading from a .csv file, by default, the first row is considered as a header row. You need to specify that it is not. So, add `header=None` in `read_csv`. Like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dataset.decode('utf-8')), header=None)
```

Also, following is one of the ways of getting your desired output:

```
data=[]
for r1, r2, r3 in df.values:
    data.append([r1,r2,r3])
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if the above answer worked for you?